# Mostrar un process que se inicializa WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public void IniciarServicio()
{
    if (_proceso == null || _proceso.HasExited)
    {
        _proceso = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                WorkingDirectory = _directorio,
                FileName = _nombreServicio,
                Arguments = _argumentos,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            }
        };

        proceso.Start();
    }    
}       

public void MostrarConsola()
{
    _proceso.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    _proceso.Refresh();

     ShowWindow(_proceso.MainWindowHandle, ShowWindowCommands.Normal);
    _proceso.Refresh();
       
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, ShowWindowCommands nCmdShow);
```

Me ejecuta el proceso (aplicación de consola) que necesito sin que me lo muestre por pantalla. el problema esta cuando le mando que me lo muestre, no lo hace.

Lo que necesito es que me ejecute de forma oculta el proceso y si yo le mando la orden de  `MostrarConsola()` me muestre el programa en pantalla

Answer (score 2):

Un programa de consola no cuenta con UI, ni con una ventana asociada por lo que `_proceso.MainWindowHandle` siempre es cero.

Lo que tu vez en pantalla es la consola (la terminal) que es otro programa, el cual ejecuta tu aplicación, entonces lo que debes hacer es obtener el `WindowHandle` de la consola no de tu programa.

Para esto puedes buscarla por su nombre, el cual es el mismo nombre de tu aplicación (con toda la ruta), en tu caso `_nombreServicio`

```
public void MostrarConsola()
{
   IntPtr handle = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, _nombreServicio);
   ShowWindow(handle, 5);    
}
//AGREGAR ESTO
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
```